# Insert/Save a pdf created using FPDF into the database

Tags: php, sql, blob, sql-insert, fpdf

Using the fpdf library to generate a PDF file and insert file into the database.

I am using the following code:

```
$content = $pdf->Output($pname.'', 'S');

$sql = "INSERT into data(name) values('".addslashes($content)."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "success";

} else {
    echo "Error: ";
}

$conn->close();
```

But using this, the file which is saved in the database is in binary format not PDF format which upon downloading doesn't seem right...

How do I fix this and get my file to be saved into database with `.pdf` extension?

Comment: Is the question solved? The answer given below looks promising. Have you tried it? Did it work? No? Did you tell them about it? What do you get back, "Error: " or other?

Comment: "in binary format not pdf format" doesn't make sense. PDF is a binary format.

Comment: And you should write `$content = $pdf->Output( 'S');`.

Comment: Simply remove `addslashes` from your insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `base64_encode()` instead of `addslashes()` this prevents trouble with binary data due to the conversion. You need to reverse this by using `base64_decode()` when reading from the DB.

A better option would be to use a BLOB column in your DB and the LOB feature of a PHP DB driver. For PDO this would be something like this:

```
$pdo = new \PDO(...);
$fp = fopen('data://' . $content, 'rb');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("insert into data (name) values (?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $fp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->execute();
```

This solution stores binary data unmodified in the DB.

Comment: No need to waste 33% storage space (not to mention the extra CPU) with Base64.